# How do you allow joints in a character to fall freely based on gravity?

Tags: unity, collider, joints

I am building a game in Unity in which a character falls down on death. Is it possible to make the joints fall and bend based on gravity? That is to leave the joints fully dependent on gravity and colliders and not any skeletal animation.

Comment: This is called a "ragdoll" - [you can find lots of existing tutorials, guides, and documentation about setting up ragdolls in Unity](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=unity+ragdoll), including assets designed to help. Can you walk us through how you've tried setting up your ragdolls so far based on this information, and where you're stuck?

Comment: Thanks for the information. I actually am new to Unity and found some information on Ragdolls thanks to your answer. I looked at the documentation a little it and it is good.

Comment: If you've solved your problem, would you care to document the steps you took to solve it as an answer below? It could help other users in future who need help figuring this out.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know how to use a RagDoll. First, you should try the [Ragdoll wizard](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/wizard-RagdollWizard.html). You should also look at [Brackley's video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DInV-jHm9rk) on this. Find a rigged body on the asset store and turn on the physics debugger and use the ragdoll wizard on it. Then just play around with the colliders and joints.

Comment: This answer would be better if it included the main points about the ragdoll wizard and working with ragdolls that you hope a future reader will glean from those links, so it holds up and has usefulness even if the links rot.